# error: void cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a library which provides maps marker animations, but when I try to add some advanced methods, it throws me an error on the second one ".withFillColor(Color.BLUE)" which says: error: void cannot be dereferenced.

```
// mMap is GoogleMap object, latLng is the location on map from which ripple should start
    actualUbicacion = new LatLng(3.385264, -76.526551);
    mapRipple = new MapRipple(mMap, actualUbicacion, this)
            .withNumberOfRipples(3) //int
            .withFillColor(Color.BLUE) //here I get the error
            .withStrokeColor(Color.BLACK) //if I delete the previous one, the next one gets the error
            .withStrokewidth(10)      // 10dp
            .withDistance(2000)      // 2000 metres radius
            .withRippleDuration(12000)    //12000ms
            .withTransparency(0.5f);
    mapRipple.startRippleMapAnimation();      //in onMapReadyCallBack

Error:(623, 17) error: void cannot be dereferenced
```

Comment: What is the return type of `withNumberOfRipples`? Can you link to Javadoc of this class?

Comment: It is supposed to be int. But im not entirely sure. This is the first time I use this library ):.

withFillColor and withStrokeColor are also integers.

Comment: I would also expect that methods beginning with `with` were used in combination with method chaining, but apparently the developer of `GoogleMapsRippleEffect` didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`From Code`](https://github.com/gursuasik/GoogleMapsRippleEffect/blob/master/googlemapsrippleeffect/src/main/java/com/arsy/maps_library/MapRipple.java)

The return type is `void`

```
public void withNumberOfRipples(int numberOfRipples) {
    if (numberOfRipples > 4 || numberOfRipples < 1)
        numberOfRipples = 4;
    this.numberOfRipples = numberOfRipples;
}
```

so you cannot chained your function calls , you need to invoke every function on `MapRipple` instance, not on `void`

Solution : reduce the calls to single level

```
mapRipple = new MapRipple(mMap, actualUbicacion, this);
mapRipple.withNumberOfRipples(3);
mapRipple.withFillColor(Color.BLUE);
mapRipple.withStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
mapRipple.withStrokewidth(10);      // 10dp
mapRipple.withDistance(2000);      // 2000 metres radius
mapRipple.withRippleDuration(12000);    //12000ms
mapRipple.withTransparency(0.5f);
mapRipple.startRippleMapAnimation();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem (:. I'm new at code, and I'm really shocked by how easy you find out what the problem is and how to solve it. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @MateoOrobioDeLaCruz i am glad that i could help, keep it up ,happy coding